# Is a graphics card change necessary?

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card

I have an HP Probook 450 G6 with Windows 10, an NVIDIA MX130, and an Intel UHD Graphics 620. How will I know what GPU Windows 10 is using, how can I change it, will it have a bad effect on the display resolution, and will it boot and can I still see windows???

Answer (score 0):

> How will I know what GPU Windows 10 is using

With the default configuration everything is rendered and displayed using Intel's integrated iGPU, unless configured otherwise in NVIDIA Control Panel. The driver comes with a built-in list of games and programs that should use the dGPU.

You can also enable a notification area icon that appears when the dGPU is enabled and can be clicked to see which programs use it. It's enabled with a checkbox in some menu of the NVIDIA Control Panel (can't remember which one).

You can also right-click program icons and use appropriate menu items to run them with integrated or dedicated GPU for this one time only.

In some laptops some video outputs are physically connected to the NVIDIA dGPU, in which case everything on displays connected to these outputs is rendered using dGPU. It's quire rare though. In most laptops the Intel iGPU is responsible for displaying everything, no matter which GPU renders it.

> how can I change it

It used to be the NVIDIA Control Panel. You can access it by right-clicking the desktop. Then select *3D settings* from the left pane.

There are three basic settings: run everything with iGPU, run everything with dGPU and choose automatically (default, per app config-based). On the 2nd tab you can edit the list of programs.

2019 builds of Windows 10 have integrated GPU switching into the OS. I'm not sure if new laptops already use this integration and to what extent. The relevant settings are then in Windows's settings.

> will it have a bad effect on the display resolution

The resolution will be whatever you configure it to be. Resolution doesn't change by itself on PCs like it does on consoles.

> will it boot and can I still see windows

I don't understand what you're asking.